# Random Coin Toss in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) gives an exercise to implement the following function:

```
-- make a function that simulates tossing a function 3 times
import System.Random

tossCoin3 :: Int -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
tossCoin3 x = 
    let (num1, gen1) = random (mkStdGen x)   :: (Int, StdGen)
        (num2, gen2) = random (gen1)         :: (Int, StdGen)
        (num3, _)    = random (gen2)         :: (Int, StdGen)

    in (convertToBool num1, convertToBool num2, convertToBool num3)
    where convertToBool y = if y `mod` 2 == 0 then True else False
```

I would've mapped a list of `[num1, num2, num3]` with the `convertToBool`, and then convert to a 3-tuple. But then I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921345/how-do-i-convert-a-list-to-a-tuple-in-haskell).

Please critique my implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Converting a `Bool` to a `Bool` with an `if`

`if` tests `Bool` values and returns results. You’re using it to return `True` if the input is `True`, and `False` if the input is `False`:

```
convertToBool y = if y `mod` 2 == 0 then True else False
```

But that’s just the identity function. You can remove the `if`:

```
convertToBool y = y `mod` 2 == 0
```

## Useless parentheses

```
random (gen1)
random (gen2)
```

## Generating random `Int`s rather than the type you wish to get directly

You’re using [`random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#v%3arandom) to generate an `Int`. That’s fine if you want an `Int`—but you want a `Bool`. Sure, you can calculate a `Bool` out of one, but [`random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#v%3arandom) can also give you a `Bool` directly. This would simplify your implementation.

I feel it’s necessary to point out the dangers of limiting random numbers to a range with modulo. In this case, it’s not actually a problem, but pretend you want to generate a number between 0 and 6, and the random number generator you have gives you numbers between 0 and 9. If you used modulo, you’d map:

```
0, 6 --> 0
1, 7 --> 1
2, 8 --> 2
3, 9 --> 3
4    --> 4
5    --> 5
6    --> 6
```

That’s not a very even distribution. The problem arises because 7 and 10 do not share a factor. It’s not relevant to you because you’re trying to generate something in the range 0 to 1 (two values) and two is a factor of the number of values in `Int`, but it’s something to be aware of nonetheless.

## Dependence on [`mkStdGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#v%3amkStdGen)

Right now, you let the user pass in a seed that is then passed to [`mkStdGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#v%3amkStdGen). That works, I suppose, but it would be more flexible if you pushed that responsibility to the user, because then the user can create an [`StdGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#t%3aStdGen) however they desire (with, say, [`getStdGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#v%3agetStdGen)). Your signature would then look like this:

```
coinToss3 :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
```

You could even change your definition to allow any [`RandomGen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html#t%3aRandomGen) instance:

```
coinToss3 :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
```

## Potential cleanup with [`MonadRandom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) and [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative)

At your current point in Learn You A Haskell, you haven’t learned about [`Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#t%3aMonad) or [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative) yet, so you may want to ignore this for now and take a look at it later, but using [`MonadRandom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) and [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative), your code can be considerably shortened:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Random

coinToss3 :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
coinToss3 = evalRand $ (,,) <$> random <*> random <*> random
```